# Changing values of a dice roll

Tags: r, sample, dice

So let's say I roll 5 dice.

The code to simulate the rolls would be

`Rolls<-sample(1:6, 5, replace=TRUE)`

and that's if I want to store my rolls under the object `Rolls`.

Now let's say for some reason I don't want there to be more than 2 sixes. That means if I roll, for example,  6 3 5 6 6 1 would I be able to re-roll one of the 6 values into a new value so that there are only 2 values of 6 and 4 values that are not 6?

Any support would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Also, just another question I have, might as well ask it here, how do I remove values from a sample? So, let's say I want to ask the user to delete a roll and then remove the value they say from the sample, how would I do that?

Comment: The second question depends on how would the user specify which roll to delete, is he going to say the place of the roll on the vector ("delete the third row"), or something else?

Comment: So lets say we use the roll in my first question, we ask the user "Which roll would you like to remove?" and lets say they choose 3. How would I then remove that 3 value or any value they choose?

Comment: So the user would be targeting a specific value rather than a position for the value, however, lets say they choose 3, I would be fine with a code that would remove the value based on its position. What I'm saying is if they choose 3, for example, a code that removes the 2nd value in the sample (which is where 3 is) would also be fine for me

Comment: Ok, the only problem is as you have `replace=TRUE` you might have more than one 3 value, in that case would you like to remove all of the 3's?

Comment: No, In my case I'd like to only remove one of the value they choose. I think explaining my scenario a bit more may help, what I'm trying to do is take two values from the sample, add them and put the new value in the sample, also removing the two values that were used in the addition. So let's say I choose 3 and 6 from my previous sample, I'd like to add 9 to the sample and remove one of the 6's and the 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solution without loops could be:

```
condition = which(Rolls==6)
if(length(condition)>=3){
  Rolls[condition[3:length(condition)]] = sample(1:5, length(condition)-2, replace=TRUE)
}
```

`condition` states the places in Rolls with 6's, if there's more than 2, you select the third one onward `Rolls[condition[3:length(condition)]]` and re-sample them.

And the second question could be something like:

```
remove = 3
Rolls = Rolls[-which(Rolls==remove)[1]]
```

You can easily put those into functions if you like

**Edit 1**

To make the second answer a bit more interactive, you can build a function for it:

```
remove.roll = function(remove, rolls){
   rolls = rolls[-which(rolls==remove)[1]]}
```

And then the user can call the function with whatever `remove` he likes. You can also make a program that takes information from the prompt:

```
remove = readline(prompt="Enter number to remove: ")
print(Rolls = Rolls[-which(Rolls==remove)[1]])
```

Comment: Just a quick question, your answer to my second question works perfectly, however, could I also ask the user for a value to remove, store this as an object (let's call it "Player_Remove") and then set "remove = Player_Remove", is this possible or does "remove" have to be set to a numeric value?

Comment: Ok, so in my code I use a prompt, I set "first_number <- readline(prompt="Enter the first number: ") and again but for "second_number", i then add these two using new_number<-(first_number + second_number). Can I use first_number and second_number the same way you've used "remove" ?

Comment: So i'd have something like print(Rolls = Rolls[-which(Rolls==first_number)[1]]) ?

Comment: I guess so, i need more context of the whole program to say for sure, if you want we can continue this question in a chat room: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230192/changing-values-of-a-dice-roll

Answer (score 3):

if i understood it correctly, that should work:

```r
n <- 10
(Rolls<-sample(1:6, n, replace=TRUE))
#>  [1] 6 2 4 1 1 6 5 2 1 6
(Nr_of_six <- sum(6 == Rolls))
#> [1] 3

while (Nr_of_six > 1) {
    extra_roll <- sample(1:6, 1, replace=TRUE)
    second_six <- which(Rolls==6)[2]
    Rolls[second_six] <- extra_roll
    print(Rolls)

    Nr_of_six <- sum(6 == Rolls)
}
#>  [1] 6 2 4 1 1 4 5 2 1 6
#>  [1] 6 2 4 1 1 4 5 2 1 3
print(Rolls)
#>  [1] 6 2 4 1 1 4 5 2 1 3
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

We can make this a fun demonstration of a use case for `scan()`. You can input the position of the values that you want to replace. Note that you need to hand `scan()` each position value piece by piece and hit enter after every one, in the end you can end the input by handing over an empty string `""` and pressing enter.

**Code**

```
dice.roll <- function(){
  # Initial toss
  Rolls <- sample(seq(1, 6), 5, replace=TRUE)
  
  # Communicate
  cat("The outcome of the dice roll was:", "\n\n", Rolls, "\n\n", 
      "would you like to reroll any of those values ?", "\n",
      "If yes enter the positions of the values you would \n like to replace, else just input an empty string.")
  
  # Take input 
  tmp1 <- scan(what = "")
  
  # Replace
  Rolls[as.numeric(tmp1)] <- sample(seq(1, 6), length(tmp1), replace=TRUE)
  
  # Return
  cat("You succesfully replaced", length(tmp1), "elements. Your rolls now look as follows: \n\n", 
      Rolls)
}

dice.roll()

# The outcome of the dice Roll was: 
#
#  6 4 6 3 4 
#
#  would you like to reroll any of those values ? 
#  If yes enter the positions of the values you would 
#  like to replace, else just input an empty string.
# 1: 1
# 2: 3
# 3: ""
# Read 2 items
# You succesfully replaced 2 elements. Your set now looks as follows 
#
#  2 4 2 3 4
```

Please note that this function is just a quick write-up to properly implement this you should use a `while` statement or `recursion` to repeat the replacement as often as you'd like. Additionally, before actually using this one would have to insert `if` statements that handle inputs that are too long and other user behavior that could cause an error.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my version of this function that uses recursion to roll extra values so that we only have no more than 2 `6s`. Pay attention that I put `rolls` vector outside of the function so in order to replace third, fourth or ... `6` from inside the function we use complex assignment operator `<<-`.
I personally chose to modify the first `6` value in a run of 3 `6s` or more.

```
rolls <- sample(1:6, 6, replace = TRUE)

n_six <- function() {
  n <- length(rolls[rolls == 6])
  
  if(n <= 2) {
    return(rolls)
  } else {
    extra <- sample(1:6, 1, replace = TRUE)
    rolls[which(rolls == 6)][1] <<- extra
  }
  n_six()
}

# Imagine our rolls would be a vector with 3 six values like this

rolls <- c(1, 2, 6, 5, 6, 6)

> n_six()
[1] 1 2 3 5 6 6       # First 6 was replaced

# Or our rolls contains 4 six values

rolls <- c(1, 6, 6, 5, 6, 6)

> n_six()
[1] 1 4 1 5 6 6       # First 2 6s have been replaced
```

And so on ...